# String manipulation in DBT - Jinja

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I want to develop a macro that will loop rows from a seeding query's result and create a dynamic query for another task.

Let's assume my row would be similar to

```
<agate.Row: ('product_available', Decimal('0.6'), 'Positive')>
<agate.Row: ('product_quality', Decimal('0.5'), 'Negative')>
```

I intend to generate an array selection for downstream queries which have `my_udf` that will take arguments from my seeding query's result. For example,

```
my_udf("product_available", 0.6, 'Positive')
my_udf("product_quality", 0.5, 'Negative')
```

The problem that I have is some arguments are actual column names, while others are values. Hence, column names should have double quotes, while value must have single quote. For instance, `"product_available"` vs `'Positive'`

My code is

```
{% macro generate_list_select_from(seeding_query) %}
    {# ... other code to execute my seeding query ... #}

    {# loop query goes here  #}
    {% for i in results_list %}
      
      {% set item = "my_udf( {{ i[0] }} , {{ i[1] }}, '{{ i[2] }}' )" %}

      {{items.append(item)}}

    {% endfor %}


    {{ return(items) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Below is output when I use my macro

```
select foo_column,  
       my_udf( {{ i[0] }} , {{ i[1] }}, '{{ i[2] }}' ),
       my_udf( {{ i[0] }} , {{ i[1] }}, '{{ i[2] }}' )
from foo_table
```

My question is how to create a such string?

Update:

- Tried other way, `{% set item = "my_udf(" + {{i[0]}} + ")" %}`, I end up with a compilation error `expected token ':', got '}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Don't nest your curlies](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/dont-nest-your-curlies).

`~` is the string concatenation operator in jinja. You could use that to build up your function args, including the single quotes:

```
{% set item = "my_udf(" ~ i[0] ~ ", " ~ i[1] ~ ", '" ~ i[2] ~ "' )" %}
```

This is pretty hard to read, though. I'd probably add a macro called `quoted`:

```
{% macro quoted(s) %}
'{{ s }}'
{% endmacro %}
```

And then use the [`join` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.join) to concatenate the items of a list:

```
{% set args = [i[0], i[1], quoted(i[2])] %}
{% set item = "my_udf(" ~ args | join(", ") ~ ")" %}
```

Lastly, if the purpose of this macro is to template SQL, then you don't need to use `return(items)`. You should just have the body of the macro template the string you want (see the `quoted` macro above). That dramatically simplifies things:

```
{% macro quoted(s) %}
'{{ s }}'
{% endmacro %}

{% macro generate_list_select_from(seeding_query) %}
    {# ... other code to execute my seeding query ... #}

    {# loop query goes here  #}
    {% for i in results_list %}
      {% set args = [i[0], i[1], quoted(i[2])] %}
      my_udf({{ args | join(", "}}){% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}
```